# Doesn't create table

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I have 3 files: connect.js, db.js, and index.js.

connect.js:

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
  user:"postgre",
  password:"yarmolla10",
  host:"27.0.0.1",
  port: 5432,
  database:"trpz"
});

module.exports = client;
```

db.js:

```
const client = require('./connect.js');

 let query = async (query) => {
  await client.connect();
  console.log("connected to db");
  console.log("Started querying");
  await client.query(query, (err, res) => {
      console.log(query);
      if(err)
      console.log(err);
      else{
    console.log("done");
      }
    })
    await client.end();
  }

module.exports = {
    query
}
```

and in index.js just call this function:

```
const db = require('./models/db.js');
...
let info = `CREATE TABLE Image2 (
    Id        serial,
    FullName  varchar(255)
  );
  ALTER TABLE Image2 ADD CONSTRAINT pkImage2 PRIMARY KEY (Id);
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX akImage2FullName ON Image2 (FullName);`

db.query(info);
...
```

I double checked right info in connect.js, and execute my code, but nothing happened, when I rewrite code without function pass(Just call node db.js from terminal and deleted all functions) it started to work.

What is my problem? Where is mistake?

Comment: are the files db.js and conntect.js inside a folder called models?

Comment: Yes, I rechecked all code twice for stupid mistakes before I post this question.